# How to listen for Firebase task completion?

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

In this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2), their Firebase code is scattered through out the controller. This makes it easy to reload a tableview when Firebase returns since your `reload()` code is in the existing `.observe()`.

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "completed").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
  var newItems: [GroceryItem] = []

  for item in snapshot.children {
    let groceryItem = GroceryItem(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
    newItems.append(groceryItem)
  }

  self.items = newItems
  self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

How can the above be handled if the Firebase code is in a class? I still need the tableview to reload, but only after Firebase returns. It looks like this:

```
f.performCompletedQuery()
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

`f.performCompletedQuery()` will execute but the code path will continue on while data is still being retrieved from Firebase. `self.tableView.reloadData()` will then fire and the table will be empty (because Firebase hasn't yet returned).

I guess I'm needing to replicate Firebase's observe, but expose it on the class and piggy back off the existing observe? Seems a little convoluted. Is there a better way? Maybe just block and display and animation?

Comment: Considered adding a completionBlock : in your performCompletedQuery()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the completion handler to achive this.
   example:

```
func queryOrdered(completion: (_ result: [Any]) -> ()) {
    // request here
    // getting response check on error
    // set completion for returned itmes if success
    completion([1, 2, 3])
}

// call the function
queryOrdered { [unowned self] (arr) in

    // get returned items
    self.myitems = arr
    // reload the table on main queue
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't using .observe() anymore? What is `[unowned self]`?

Comment: Got it working now. Only thing is, I don't need a param for the completion block but I don't know how to remove it. Do you have some idea on that?

Comment: @4thSpace simply put void function as param, like this:
func queryOrdered(completion: () -> ()) {
    completion()
}

,[unowned self] used for omit the retain cycle for self.